# this.getDoc() is null in FF using tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce, rte

I got the problem that when i load my page i immediatly receive the error : `this.getDoc() is null`

The function `getBody()` of `Editor.js` gets called and the document seems to be not available

```
getBody : function() {
    return this.bodyElement || this.getDoc().body;
},
```

In this case getBody() has been triggered by the destroy() function in a gecko code block.

```
destroy : function(s) {
        var t = this;

        // One time is enough
        if (t.destroyed)
            return;

        // We must unbind on Gecko since it would otherwise produce the pesky "attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope" message
        if (isGecko) {
            Event.unbind(t.getDoc());
            Event.unbind(t.getWin());
            Event.unbind(t.getBody()); // here is the relevant getBody() call
        }
```

Destroy has been triggered by the function addUnload of tinymce.js

```
o.func.call(o.scope, 1);
```

What can i do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

happened to me when i upgraded jquery..

to resolve it just upgrade jquery to the latest version and also tinymce to the latest version..

i have found other solution for this problem while searching the net.. try to remove the filemanager,imagemanager form plugin list. When it is not set up properly it may cause some issues.

Comment: +1 thanks for your reply. i am not using filemanager and/or imagemanager (they are not in my plugin list). concerning jQuery and tinymce. i might be able to upgrade to the latesttinymce version, but due to jQuery conflicts with our CMS i won't ba able to update jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Although this was already answered, I had the same problem but the solution was different than anything listed here. Essentially even with the latest and greatest of both jQuery and TinyMCE, I found that if 'external_plugins' is empty in the options for tinymce.init(), this error will occur upon unload/removal of the tinymce element.

For context, it happened to me after closing a bootstrap modal with tinymce and only during that, and it only happened when 'external_plugins' was empty, either null, empty object, or empty string, it doesn't like it there unless something is defined.